# converting SQL to cakephp ORM

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, orm

So I have this query that I am trying to convert to cake ORM and I do not know how to go about it.

I have a user table and a word table. Users have many words (thats the relationship). I want to write a query that will give me the users that have added the most words in the system. This is the current query I wrote but I am having trouble converting it to cakephp ORM syntax, any ideas?

```
SELECT 
    users.username, 
    COUNT(word) AS n 
FROM 
    users AS users 
        INNER JOIN words AS words 
            ON users.userid=words.userid 
GROUP BY 
    users.username 
ORDER BY 
    n DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to write the query:- In controller you can write as -

```
 $options = array(
             'fields' => array(
                  'User.name',
                  'COUNT(Word.id) as word_count',
                 ),
          'group'  => 'Word.user_id',
          'order'  => 'word_count DESC',
        );           

$users = $this->User->Word->find('first', $options);
debug($users);
```

In User model you have to write:

```
public $hasMany = 'Word';
```

In Word model you have to write:

```
public $belongsTo = 'User';
```